# Binary Serialization conversion for properties that have types

Tags: c#, binary-serialization

I have binary serialized objects when that were originally serialized with a property that was DateTime. The property has now changed to DateTimeOffset.  The deserialization now throws the exception

`Object of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be converted to type 'System.DateTimeOffset'.`

Is it possible to having something that can do a conversion to the datetimeoffset while it deserializing?  i.e.  a custom deserializer or onDeserializtion or extension or attribute...

any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Have you experimented with `IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization`?

Comment: More info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480804/how-can-i-override-deserialization-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you share some code?